# Solve an equation with $e^{(x-2)}=e^{4}\cdot e^{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, exponential-function

$$e^{(x-2)}=e^{4}e^\sqrt{x}$$

I know that $x = 9$ and I can show the calculations like this:

$$e^{(x-2)} = e^{\sqrt{x}+4}$$

and now I need to get the $x$ to the right side but I dont know how.

Comment: $\ln(e^x) = x$ when $x > 0$, so $e^{(x-2)} = e^{\sqrt{x}+4} \Rightarrow x-2 = \sqrt{x}+4$

Comment: @kba As Git Gud pointed out, the identity $\ln(e^x)=x$ holds true even if $x\le0$.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Since the function $f(x)=e^x$ is **injective** (or **one-to-one**), we know that $e^a=e^b \implies a=b$. So we may equate exponents to obtain:
$$
x-2=\sqrt{x}+4
$$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Apply $\log$ to both sides of the equality. Rememeber that $(\forall y\in \Bbb R)\left(\log (e^y)=y)\right)$.

To solve an equation that looks like $ay+b\sqrt y+c=0$, introduce the variable change $w=\sqrt y$ to get $aw^2+bw+c=0.$

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$x-2=\sqrt x+4\stackrel{t:=\sqrt x}\implies t^2-t-6=0\implies (t-3)(t+2)=0\;\ldots$$

Note that it **must** be $\,x\ge 0\,$ .

Comment: Also, since we have $x-6=\sqrt{x}$ and the right hand side of this equation is (by the definition of a square root) guaranteed to be nonnegative, we know that the left hand side must also be nonnegative so that $x-6\ge0 \iff x\ge6$.

Comment: $x^2-13x+36=0$ has the solution $+-i\sqrt{23}$

Comment: @MikaelJensen, two things (1) What does your comment have to do with this question/answer/comment?, and (2) The quadratic you wrote down has the solutions $$\frac{13\pm\sqrt{169-144}}2=\frac{13\pm 5}2=\begin{cases}9\\{}\\4\end{cases}$$

Comment: I thought the equation was equal to x-6=sqrt{x}

Comment: I thought the equation was equal to sqrt{x}

Comment: 1) I meant to use Adrianos approach above, square both sides and find the solutions in an easier way than some of the above. ii) Then I made a strange mistake, I must have entered $x^2-23=0$  which means I probably forgot the x in the term -13x. The whole event gives an indication why I am not a mathematician.